# Formatting .txt file before usage of readlines()

Tags: python, quicksort, readlines

Because I need to sort a `.txt` file with quicksort, I used `readlines()` to use my function. The problem is that it isn't formatted like before the usage of `readlines()`.

```
f = open(filename)
array = f.readlines()
```

Then I used my quicksort function.

How the Input File looks like:

```
12.01.2020 bcd
05.02.1990 efd
13.04.1992 cba
```

How it should look like after quicksort:

```
05.02.1990 efd
13.04.1992 cba
12.01.2020 bcd
```

but in my code it's looking like this:

```
'05.02.1990\tefd\n', '13.04.1992\tcba\n', '12.01.2020\tbcd\n'
```

Any Suggestions how i can correct my usage of `readlines()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually how readlines is used. It generates a list of strings that are found in your text file. As you can see each string is separated by a `,`, the tabs are represented as `\t` and the new line is represented as `\n`.

You can simply write the array to a file again to get the wanted output.

```py
with open('sorted.txt', 'w') as of:
    for s in sorted:
        of.write(s)
```

PS. what you're printing is the content of your output list, this will replace things like tabs and newline characters with their unicode representation. If you loop through your output and print the content, you'll see the output that you want to see.

```py
for s in output:
    print(s)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know have the same structure as the Input but now there are additional empyt lines between each line. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Ah when you print this is the case yes, this wouldn't be the case if you write it to a file.
`print()` adds a `\n` character as well, to solve this you can use `print(s, end='')` this will suppress the newline character from `print`